# Highchart prevent auto reload

Tags: jquery, highcharts, responsive-design

I am using multiple stack charts in a single web page.
But when I am zooming in the page, the datalabels of all the highcharts are automatically replaced by that of the latest values.

Even if I open a firebug same is the issue on closing the firebug. This is strange. And I feel the highchart is automatically reloading. Since I have checked that my function is not being recalled in either of the above cases.

Please find below a code snippet -

```
--Method call
$(".percent").each(function(index){
    var id = "percentage"+index;
    stackChart(id, array);
});
```

--Highchart method -

```
function stackChart(id, array, height, width){
         .
         .
         .
         chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           .
           .
           .
          series: [{
             name:"1",
             data: [(array[2]/(array[0]+array[1]+array[2]))*100],
             formatter: function() {
                return array[2];
             }
          },{
             name:"2",
             data: [(array[1]/(array[0]+array[1]+array[2]))*100],
             formatter: function() {
                return array[1];
             }
          })
    }
```

Comment: i do not get the problem.. when you zoom, or resize, it may be that the chart redraws (e.g. if the page is responsive), but what is wrong with that?

Comment: Yeah but while redrawing, the chart is replacing all the datalabels with the last chart's datalabel

Comment: maybe you could create jsfiddle or show it on some live example, this way it is hard to tell

Comment: Could you post full Highcharts code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var flag = false;

if(!flag){
$(".percent").each(function(index){
    var id = "percentage"+index;
    stackChart(id, array);
});
flag = true;
}
```

It uses `flag` to prevent auto reload.